# Returning names of students in a dataframe that got above a certain value for all examinations

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe `marks` that is structured as so:

```
student    exam_marks
Lucy         0.56
Lucy         0.63
Lucy         0.81
Lucy         0.66
Devon        0.75
Devon        0.77
Sara         0.84
Sara         0.90
Sara         0.87
Jake         0.76
Jake         0.88
Jake         0.81
Jake         0.72
```

I would like to have a new dataframe returning the names of the students who have scored above 80% on **all** exams. In this instance my expected output would be a dataframe containing just Sara.

Does anyone know how this could be done? I'm quite a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We group by 'student', `filter` the rows where `all` the 'exam_marks' are greater than 0.80, get the `distinct` rows and `pull` the 'student'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(student) %>%
     filter(all(exam_marks > 0.80)) %>%
     ungroup %>%
     distinct(student) %>%
     pull(student)
#[1] "Sara"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(student = c("Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Devon", 
"Devon", "Sara", "Sara", "Sara", "Jake", "Jake", "Jake", "Jake"
), exam_marks = c(0.56, 0.63, 0.81, 0.66, 0.75, 0.77, 0.84, 0.9, 
0.87, 0.76, 0.88, 0.81, 0.72)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Comment: Hi, this worked very well, thanks a lot. Would there be any way to have the output stored as a vector? I'm not very familiar with piping.

Comment: Oh, think I got it... Just added the object distinction at the beginning. Thanks a lot for your help, appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

With `base R`, you can use the following code to extract the name of student who is over 0.8 for all exams:

```
r <- unique(with(df,student[ave(exam_marks,student,FUN = function(x) all(x >=0.8))>0]))
```

which gives

```
> r
[1] "Sara"
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(student = c("Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Devon", 
"Devon", "Sara", "Sara", "Sara", "Jake", "Jake", "Jake", "Jake"
), exam_marks = c(0.56, 0.63, 0.81, 0.66, 0.75, 0.77, 0.84, 0.9, 
0.87, 0.76, 0.88, 0.81, 0.72)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you could do as follows. The `aggregate` function allows you to group a dataframe on specified variables and apply a function on each group. The `all` function tests that all members of a group satisfy the required condition. You can then filter for the rows where the condition is TRUE:

```
x <- aggregate(exam_marks ~ student, df, FUN = function(y) all(y > 0.8))
x[x$exam_marks == TRUE, 1, drop = FALSE]
# output
  student
4    Sara
```

I created the dataframe `df` as below:

```
df <- structure(list(student = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Devon", "Jake", "Lucy", 
"Sara"), class = "factor"), exam_marks = c(0.56, 0.63, 0.81, 
0.66, 0.75, 0.77, 0.84, 0.9, 0.87, 0.76, 0.88, 0.81, 0.72)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```